# Recalculate order grand total including discount and tax

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, tax, discount, order-totals

I have an order data without shipping included, i tried to  re-calculate total order when adding shipping price like this:

```
$shippingAmount = '30000';
$quote = $this->getQuote();
$quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getGrandTotal() + $shippingAmount);
```

but the above code won't recalculate total discount and tax

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the Shipping method, you should tell magento to Collect Totals again. Refer below code:

```
$onepage = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
$quote = $onepage->getQuote();
$shippingMethod = 'shipping_method_code';
$onepage->saveShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
$onepage->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
```

The above code will work if you have a shipping method with code 'shipping_method_code' for the shipping address you selected. Read the tutorial to learn how to create a shipping method [Here](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/) or use any existing shipping methods like USPS, UPS, Flat Rate etc.

Comment: that makes my grand total 0

Comment: Paste your code